# Can I make Dialogflow intents require atleast one of the trained entities?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I know how to make intents require any parameter value, after which the intent will force to get the value; but is it possible to make it force to get **atleast** one of the given entity parameters ?

Comment: Hi, I am stuck with the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: I ended up using webhooks only.. Few lines on node would do. Go along the lines mentioned by @lukedavis

Answer (score 3):

You could enable webhook fulfillment for that intent and if no entities were provided, reprompt the user for at least one of a list of entities.